# Why does my calculator show -2^2 as -4

Tags: arithmetic, calculator

I'm worried that this will be a spanner in the works when I'm using a calculator in an exam , I know that $-2^2= 4$ since $(-2) \cdot (-2) = 4 $. So why does my calculator show it as negative 4 ? Does anyone know if there is a way to reset my calculator so it doesn't do this? The make and model is Casio fx-83ES.

Comment: $(-2)^2 = 4$, but $-2^2 = -(2^2) = -4$, the precedence of exponentiation is higher than that of unary minus.

Comment: I see, Thanks !

Comment: It depends on how the calculator parses the input; for instance `echo '-2^2' | bc` returns `4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between
$-2^2$ and $(-2)^2$ 
In the first examples you square the number two and then you apply the negative. In the second example you sqaure the number negative two then you get the desired reuslt, 4

Answer (score 1):

This is a really simple error to correct. It's order of operations: $-2^2=-(2^2)=-4$. Your calculator is correct, just use parentheses around $-2$. $(-2)^2=4≠-2^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $-2^2$ is different than $(-2)^2$, which you intend.

Reviewing the order of operations, exponentiation comes before multiplication. $-2^2 = -1 \cdot 2^2 = -1 \cdot 4 = -4$.

However $(-2)^2$ is evaluated as $(-2)^2 = 4$.

Comment: Thank you I expected It to be something relatively simple, this has cleared things up a lot :)